# How can I generate cluster graphs from java output?

Tags: java, graph, graphviz

I am looking for something similar to GraphViz, but that would allow me to generate the graphs without having to install the program on the computer. As I understand, I would have to make external calls to the program after generating a DOT file in order to make this work, but I would like to package my program into an executable jar file that runs as a Stand alone app. Is there something that would allow me to do this with JAVA?
If there are any good tutorials out there please link them here.